# CSS tabs not working with anchors on bootstrap?

Tags: css, tabs, twitter-bootstrap, toggle, anchor

#### Attempt 1

```
<div class="bs-docs-example">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a>aaa</li>
        <li><a href="#">Profile</a>fff</li>
        <li><a href="#">Messages</a>bbb</li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fXbvt/)**

I have also tried setting a `data-toggle` attribute to "tab", but that only allowed me to click between tabs, it didn't separate the aaa/fff/bbb into different tabs.

This should be possible to be done without any JavaScript.

#### Attempt 2

The closest I've gotten to a working one is:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#ter" data-toggle="tab">Stir</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#gin" data-toggle="tab">Drink</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="ter">fff</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="gin">ggg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**[JSfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3N5Hk/)**

But this didn't change the URL of the viewer to `/#ter` or `/#gin` on click. Also it doesn't seem to work normally in the fiddle...

Answer (score -1):

Your [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3N5Hk/show/) works as expected -- anchor links take you to `#gin` and `#ter`. On the other hand, I believe you need to use some JavaScript to actually change the active tab. Here's a try that uses a bit of **jQuery**:

```
<div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="active">
            <a href="#ter" data-toggle="tab">Stir</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#gin" data-toggle="tab">Drink</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane active" id="ter">fff</div>
        <div class="tab-pane" id="gin">ggg</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".nav-tabs li a").click(function() {
            var li = $(this).parent("li");
            var wch = this.getAttribute("href");
            $(li).addClass("active"); //make current li active
            $(li).siblings("li").removeClass("active"); //make others inactive
            $(".tab-content div").removeClass("active"); //make all tabs inactive first
            $(wch).addClass("active"); //activate our tab;
            return false; //don't change URL
        });
});
```

And a little demo: [little link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr3nV/16/). Note that the use of jQuery isn't needed; you can easily convert to vanilla JavaScript if you want to avoid using it.

Hope that helped!

Comment: Thanks, but at least for me (Chrome) the tab isn't changing in your link, however the text is.

Comment: @user1438003 Fixed -- sorry, I totally forgot about that!

Comment: Thanks, working a bit nicer now... but would it be possible to change the URL so I can go `#gin` or `#ter` in the URL? - Also, is it feasible to do this all in CSS?

Comment: @user1438003 That's just more JavaScript. Nope, no way to do this only in CSS.